# read xlsx file with sheet named as None. pandas xlrd

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

I have a bunch of xlsx files with sheets named as `None` (empty string) 
When I trying to read the files using `pandas`, the `xlrd` raises a `list index out of range` error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/runxlrd.py", line 332, in main
    ragged_rows=options.ragged_rows,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 416, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 791, in open_workbook_2007_xml
    x12sheet.process_stream(zflo, heading)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 528, in own_process_stream
    self_do_row(elem)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py", line 667, in do_row
    value = self.sst[int(tvalue)]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I found [this](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/issues/101) issue in `xrld` github that I think is related. 
If I change the name of the sheet, `pandas` successfully reads the file.

I can't share the files as an example (privacy issue), and when I tried to create a demo file with `None` as the sheet name, the Excel raised an invalid name error.

Packages version.

```
pkg_resources.get_distribution("xlrd").version
Out[3]: '1.1.0'
pd.__version__
Out[4]: '0.23.0'
```

Is there a way to read this file with pandas or a script (in any language) that can change the sheet names?

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to use `xlrd` to open an Excel spreadsheet? And one of the sheets is called None? I'm not sure where the xml file is used.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I mean to `xlsx` file. Pandas uses as xlrd to open `xlsx` file.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using Python 2.7, pandas 0.23.3 and xlrd 1.1.0

[image: Excel file with sheet named None]

```
>>> import xlrd
>>> import pandas
>>> xlrd_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("test.xlsx")
>>> pandas.read_excel(xlrd_workbook, engine='xlrd')
     A    B    C
0  123  456  789
```

Comment: Do u named the sheet literally None or empty string?

Comment: I typed the string None using Excel itself. It wouldn't let me leave it blank.

Comment: The error appears when it blank. 
I'm guessing it's blank because the xlsx file created as a system report.